# CSS - How to break a line only at division borders

Tags: html, css, word-break

I have the following code

http://jsfiddle.net/yXwh9/3/
and the result is 
http://jsfiddle.net/yXwh9/3/embedded/result/

The problem is that the first line is broken and "Techconnect is a group where we discuss about " comes in first line and "technology,languages,platform,development and IDE and front end development".

On the second line, I don't want this to happen. I want the line to break up exactly at the right boundary of the containing division. (I dont want `<pre>` as a solution, just because the text may not contain `<br/>` inside.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for `text-align: justify`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QGuKM/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yXwh9/4/embedded/result/

it results in unwanted whitespaces ..

Comment: I agree with Jon that "justify" is what you're looking for. Just put space after your commas. The browser is treating "technology,languages,platform,development" as one word. Change it to "technology, languages, platform, development".

Comment: @JinuJD: Please take some time to rewrite the question clearly, keeping in mind that we don't have the same screen size or resolution as you.

Comment: Here it is with justify and commas with space after them: http://jsfiddle.net/yXwh9/5/